# How can keep column width in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, grid, styles, width, ng-grid

This is my question .. 
How can keep ng-grid column width?

When I click a row on the first grid, the columns in the other grid appear "closed" even though they have the same style.
And they only "open" when I click on the column headers of the second grid.

```
.gridStyle {
border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
width: 100% !important;
height: 250px;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 13px;}
```

I show you an example to better understand.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lbmw2X5IurRhebPrDCwY?p=preview

Comment: Not sure why, but if you get rid of your `ng-hide="!mySelections[0].id_paciente"`, the width is correct.

Comment: Yes, but first I need to be hidden view. :S how i can?

Comment: You could hardcode the width, as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the width=100% in the gridStyle css to width=430px and that worked.
http://plnkr.co/edit/JNEjasHdL7VhQtF3ggEO?p=preview

```
.gridStyle {
border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
width: 430px;
height: 250px;
text-align: left;
font-family: "Arial";
font-size: 13px;
```

}

Comment: Thank you! try to do it in Live Mode and it did not work. But change in the CSS and work perfect.. (Y) :D